TSkLabel does not use theme colors for text
I'm working on a utility program for IT and one of the users really wants dark mode so I thought I would include that ability.
I'm using a TSkLabel for information display and when I switch to "Windows 11 Modern Dark" the text remains black. I immediately thought there must a setting for this but I couldn't find one.
Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Skia VCL controls are not styles like other VCL controls. You will have to apply appropriate color on style change yourself.
  SkLabel1.TextSettings.FontColor := $FF000000 or TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.GetStyleFontColor(sfTextLabelNormal);


I was afraid of that. Since the background uses the appropriate color for the selected style I was hoping there was some setting for the text too.

Background is transparent. That is why its color matches.

You can also extent the TSkLabel control to catch style message change and automatically adjust color.
